# mount a hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have third have internal hard drive would like mount in ubuntu and access in windows 10 use it as swap area for data files. I can see the drive fine in windows, write and read it, but Ubuntu gives the following error:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens when Windows is doing Fast StartUp. Go to your Windows Power settings on the Control Panel and look for the option to change the behavior of the power button and the activation of password protection. Enable the form to make changes and disable fast startup. Restart and you should have access to your disk again. My system is in spanish and it is no 10 but this is how it looks like in both.

[image: power settings(spanish)]